# Optimizing Python loop when each loop reads the result of last loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, optimization

A function that consisted of two loops (outer and inner) should be optimized - ideally by replacing Python loops with Numpy functions. The inner loop could be optimized easily (variable `inner_loop`), but can the outer loop be changed as well?

The problem is that `inner_loop` reads the vector `U`, one element of which is changed in each outer loop. If I optimize the outer loop by using the matching Numpy functions, the "recursive" element (updating `U[i]`) is lost.

```
for i in (y for y in xrange(0, n)):
    inner_loop = -np.sum(self.Y[i, :] * U) + self.Y[i, i] * U[i] + np.conjugate(self.shares[i] / U[i])
    U[i] = U_last[i] + accelerator * (1/self.Y[i,i] * inner_loop - U_last[i])
```

`U` is a vector (n dimensions), `U_last` and `self.shares` too, `Y` is a nxn matrix, U. 
For those wondering, it's part of a Gauss-Seidel power flow algorithm.

Comment: What do you need this for `for i in (y for y in xrange(0, n)):`? Simply use `for i in xrange(0, n)`

Comment: I deleted some conditions to make the code smaller and easier to read. It has its purpose in the real code.

Comment: Using xrange to provide numbers should be fast anyway. I get 100million in 2.9 seconds on my machine. You could try cython to get a bit more speed

Comment: Most `numpy` functions operate in 'parallel' - apply the operation to all elements and/or rows at once (even if the C code is sequential).  `cumsum` and the more general `ufunc.reduce(at)` are the only sequential 'builtins'.

Comment: "Flow" makes me wonder if you can redo the algorithm as an iterated matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're recursively building the array, no. You'll have to figure out another algorithm which isn't recursive, or factors out the recursive part.

---

Let's do what we can, though.

`for i in (y for y in xrange(0, n)):` is equivalent to `for i in xrange(n)`. There is no purpose for the `y`, since it is not exposed as a name.

The only place where changed values of `U` are used is in the pass to `np.sum`, so we can simplify somewhat by doing some pre-computation.

- `self.Y[i, i] * U[i]` can be `Ydiag_times_U[i]`, where `Ydiag_times_U = np.diag(Y) * U`.
- `np.conjugate(self.shares[i] / U[i])` can be `conjugate_shares_over_U[i]`, where `conjugate_shares_over_U = np.conjugate(self.shares/U)`.
- `U_last[i] + accelerator * (1/self.Y[i,i] * inner_loop - U_last[i])` can be similarly rearranged and made into `U_last_minus_accelerator_times_U_last[i] + accelerator_over_Ydiag[i] * inner_loop`, where the silliness is

  `U_last_minus_accelerator_times_U_last[i] = U_last - accelerator * U_last`
  `accelerator_over_Ydiag = accelerator/np.diag(self.Y)`

Making the changes:

```
Ydiag_times_U = np.diag(Y) * U
conjugate_shares_over_U = np.conjugate(self.shares / U)
inner_silliness = Ydiag_times_U + conjugate_shares_over_U
U_last_minus_accelerator_times_U_last[i] = U_last - accelerator * U_last
accelerator_over_Ydiag = accelerator/np.diag(self.Y)

for i in xrange(n):
    inner_loop = inner_silliness[i] - np.sum(self.Y[i, :] * U)
    U[i] = U_last_minus_accelerator_times_U_last[i] + accelerator_over_Ydiag[i] * inner_loop
```

Those are the lower-level changes. Beyond that, you can try to do some algebra to pull out the recursiveness. If you're worrying about efficiency, try doing the loop in C.

Comment: Thank you! It did indeed speed up the algorithm about ~0.5 ms on average, which is not too bad considering it only runs for 2-3 ms.